# Cannot push values with keys in an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push some values with keys to a array and I want to fetch the details with keys to show theme in the alert message;
Here is my code which I tried 
[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmszk/2/)

Html

```
<table>  

            <tr class='itemIndex'>
                <td class="id">18445</td>
                <td class="firstName">Kakali</td>
                <td class="occupation">Poultry farm</td>
                <td class="sector">Business</td>
                <td class="userInvestment">200</td>
             </tr>

            <tr class='itemIndex'>
                <td class="id">18560</td>
                <td class="firstName">Jamuna</td>
                <td class="occupation">Handloom Work</td>
                <td class="sector">Business</td>
                <td class="userInvestment">300</td>
             </tr>

            <tr class='itemIndex'>
                <td class="id">18562</td>
                <td class="firstName">Champa</td>
                <td class="occupation">Paddy processing</td>
                <td class="sector">Business</td>
                <td class="userInvestment">200</td>
             </tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var cartItem = [{id:''},{name:''},{occpation:''},{sector:''},{amount:''}];   
            $('.itemIndex').each(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var itemId= element.children('.id').text();
                var firstName = element.children('.firstName').html();
                var occupation = element.children('.occupation').html();
                var sector = element.children('.sector').html();
                var userInvestment = element.children('.userInvestment').html();
                cartItem.push[{'id':+itemId},{'name':+firstName},{'occpation':+occupation},{'sector':+sector},{'amount':+userInvestment}];
            }).promise().done(function(){
                for(var i=0;i<cartItem.length;i++)
                {               alert(cartItem.id[i],cartItem.name[i],cartItem.occupation[i],cartItem.sector[i],cartItem.amount[i]);
                } 
            });    
});
```

Comment: `alert()` does not take multiple arguments. Use `console.log()` for debugging, not `alert()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean something like this::

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var cartItem = [];   
            $('.itemIndex').each(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var itemId= element.children('.id').text();
                var firstName = element.children('.firstName').html();
                var occupation = element.children('.occupation').html();
                var sector = element.children('.sector').html();
                var userInvestment = element.children('.userInvestment').html();
                //alert(itemId);
                cartItem.push({'id':itemId,'name':firstName,'occupation':occupation,'sector':sector,'amount':userInvestment});
                //console.log( cartItem );
            }).promise().done(function(){
                 console.log( cartItem );
                for(var i=0;i<cartItem.length;i++) {
                    console.log(cartItem[i].id,cartItem[i].name,cartItem[i].occupation,cartItem[i].sector,cartItem[i].amount);
                } 
            });    
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmszk/6/)

Comment: there is no need to write the same code for each field/table cell, as class names are the same as assoc. array keys it make sense to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are doing , but consider this code (fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/vmszk/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var cart = []

$('.itemIndex').each(function() {
    var item = {}

    $(this).children().each(function() {
       item[this.className] = this.innerHTML;  
    })
    cart.push(item)        
})


$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(cart))


});
```

Answer (score 0):

There were lots of code errors as you are new to Javascript. I have fixed your errors and it is working.

Suggest you learn to use console.log instead of alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {   var cartItem = [];   $('.itemIndex').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var itemId = element.children('.id').text();
    var firstName = element.children('.firstName').html();
    var occupation = element.children('.occupation').html();
    var sector = element.children('.sector').html();
    var userInvestment = element.children('.userInvestment').html();
    cartItem.push({
      'id' : itemId,
      'name' : firstName,
      'occpation' : occupation,
      'sector' : sector,
      'amount' : userInvestment
    });   })   for ( var i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(cartItem[i]));   } });
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmszk/9/